\lstnewenvironment with broken page breaks
I have the following environment set up:
\lstdefinelanguage{prompt}{}
\lstnewenvironment{prompt}{%
  \lstset{language=prompt,
    frame=none,
    aboveskip=1.5mm,
    belowskip=1.5mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=fullflexible,
    basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    %numbers=left,
    %firstnumber=0,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    commentstyle=\color{black},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    postbreak={\mbox{$\hookrightarrow\space$}},
    tabsize=2,
    xleftmargin=1em,
    xrightmargin=0pt,
    breakindent=0pt,
    resetmargins=true,
    breakautoindent=false
  }
  \mdframed[%
  innertopmargin=5pt,
  middlelinewidth=1pt,
  outerlinewidth=9pt,outerlinecolor=white,
  innerleftmargin=3pt,
  innerrightmargin=3pt,
  leftmargin=-9pt,rightmargin=-10pt,
  skipabove=\topskip,
  skipbelow=\topskip,
  roundcorner=3pt,
  singleextra={\node[draw, fill=white,anchor=west, xshift=10pt+1pt,font=\bfseries] at (O|-P) {Prompt};},
  firstextra={\node[draw, fill=white,anchor=west, xshift=10pt+1pt,font=\bfseries] at (O|-P) {Prompt};}
  ]%
}{\endmdframed}

This works and prints well if the text block inside an instance is small enough to fit within a page:

However, when it has to be split in 2, the header is left behind in a way that looks awkward and if it is split between 3, only one line is printed per page, until the final one:
2 pages:

3 or more pages:

I have fiddled with the environment settings but haven't found a way to have sensible breaks between pages, I am wondering how to go about fixing this.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

use tcolorbox instead of mdframed.
